# Sorting complex json object without lossing data and with same structure

Tags: json, sorting

I have JSON like

```
var MyJSON = {
  "item1" : "value1",
  "item2" : {
     "somedata": "somevalue",
      "entries":[ 
        {   
         "sortitem":"ABC",
        },
        {
         "sortitem":"PQR",    
       },
       {
        "sortitem":"XYZ",    
       }
      ]  
  }
  "item3" : {
     "somedata": "somevalue",
      "entries":[ 
        {   
         "sortitem":"abc",
        },
        {
         "sortitem":"pqr",    
       },
       {
        "sortitem":"xyz",    
       }
      ]  
  }

};
```

I have to sort MyJSON on "sortitem" without changing structure and without data loss.

Comment: Please note a programming language you want to use for your task.

Comment: Please note that the problem seems to have **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Even if you get your data as JSON (e.g. via Ajax), sorting is something that is typically done on the native data structures in the language, not on JSON-serialized data.

Comment: Also post some code that you may have tried to implement in that language.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help,

```
(function (data, sField){
    function recurse (dt){
        for(prop in dt){
            if(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(dt, prop)){
                if(Object.prototype.toString.call(dt[prop]) === '[object Array]'){
                    dt[prop].sort(function(a, b){
                        if(!a[sField] || !b[sField]) return 0; 
                        return a[sField].localeCompare(b[sField]); 
                    });
                }
                else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(dt[prop]) === '[object Object]'){
                    recurse(dt[prop]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    recurse(data);
})(MyJSON, 'sortitem'); //data and sortfield
```

hope this helps.